# Will static keyword helps here

Tags: c++, static

```
    class A{
    int _a;
    public:
    /--/ void setfunc(int a)        ............. will static works here
    {
      _a=a;
    }
     int getValue(){return _a};
    };

    class B{

     public:
     void func()
     {
      /--/ setfunc(1);          ...................Dont want to create object of A.
     }
    };

    class C{

     public:
       void something()
       {
        A aa;
        cout<<aa.getValue();            ............. want a value update by                      class B setfunc
       }
     };

     int main()
      {
        B bb;
        bb.func();
        C cc;
        cc.something();
      }
```

Question : How can setfunc() can be called in another function without using that class object. Also, if it changes like setting value of "_a" via someclass B. the same value of will persist whenever I try to retrieve it in someanother class like C via getValue()

Comment: What you are trying is not possible, because `setfunc` accesses a member variable. What should `setfunc` do in your opinion if you do not call it on an object `x` of type `A`. What is it supposed to access instead of `x._a`?

Comment: You should decide if _a is a variable that belongs to each instance of class A or if all instances will share this (static) variable.

Answer (score 3):

In static function you can use only static members of class. Like this (_a is static):

```
class A {
    static int _a;
    public:
    static void setfunc(int a)
    {
      _a=a;
    }
    static int getValue(){return _a};
};
```

Otherwise, you can't do anything with non-static members:

```
class A {
    int _a;
    public:
    static void setfunc(int a)
    {
      _a=a; // Error!
    }
    static int getValue(){return _a}; // Error!
};
```